# How to play a double album using the Spotify App API?

Tags: spotify

I want to play double albums by using the Spotify app API.

For example: spotify:album:7MwNG0PSmP2Ggsdx9MHnPR 
has 26 tracks in the first album and 27 additional tracks.

I tried the following:

```
> album = spotify.models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:7MwNG0PSmP2Ggsdx9MHnPR')
> album.tracks.length
  26
> album.data.numTracks
  26
```

In the returned object (album) there isn't anything that indicated additional tracks. 
However, I am using the native Spotify player view that is provided by the API. So I am assuming that I should actually not need to deal with that issue. It should be done by the player instead.

```
spotify.models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:7MwNG0PSmP2Ggsdx9MHnPR', function(album) {
  var player = new spotify.views.Player()

  player.track = album.get(0)
  player.context = album

  $('body').append(player.node)
}
```

This is how I add the album to the player. And the player will play only the 26 tracks. Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a misconception here. One might think that "Additional tracks" are actually "hidden tracks" or "extras" that belong to the same album and disc, but they're not. Additional tracks are simply tracks that belong to albums that are considered very similar to the requested one.

Your example, Live At The Hollywood Palladium, released 2009 (spotify:album:7MwNG0PSmP2Ggsdx9MHnPR), correctly contains 26 tracks. If you enter the URI in the Spotify search field, or click on the album title in a track list, the Album App will show you 26 additional tracks. These come from Live At The Hollywood Palladium, released 2004 (spotify:album:1SdlTPJQ3QMh1eTyJ7oUeM).

Hope this helps!